# How to convert web app into saas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, saas

I have a completed asp.net mvc 3 web application which relies on a mysql database and a mssql authentication/authorization database. How should I go about converting the application into Software as a Service - specifically with relation to having multiple tenants? Should the database just have its tables segregated based on tenant ids, or should there be one database per tenant? Are there any books or good sources I can reference? I am just trying to see if there is a best practice for this, or if what I am doing is standard.

Comment: @downvoter - If this is off topic, then what exchange should it be placed in?

Answer (score 0):

**[Software as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)** is a huge industry and is rapidly growing. Major educational players are actively investing in including coursework regarding SaaS. One such institution is Unversity of Berkeley, California. They offer a free online course on **[SaaS at edx.org](https://www.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS169.1x/2012_Fall/about)**. The two professors teaching the class are highly acclaimed. The book for the course can be purchased via **[their site](http://beta.saasbook.info/)** or through **[amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984881212)**.

Note: I am in no way affiliated with the course, the University, the professors, any of the free online education sites, nor am I enrolled in the class. There is not much content available on SaaS and this is one of the *only* sources that I was able to find.

**Edit**

With regards to the database, to convert from a single tenant to a multi tenant system, an abstraction must be used in order to separate the content. However, this will undeniably multiply the amount of content by the amount of tenants in the tables resulting in slower query times. In this respect, the tables must be partitioned by tenant ranges, with views representing those partitions. These views can then be queried.

Comment: @downvoter - If you dislike the question (since I see you voted to close it and downvoted it as well) what does that have to do with the answer? If you downvote, then at least comment.